# Move Git home directory Windows 7

Tags: git

I used to have a Windows 7 laptop with 2 drives installed. I had git repositories (and the associated git home directory) on the second drive. I managed the files using git bash.

```
e:\projects\repo1\...
e:\home\me\...
```

I have re-purposed the second drive and moved the files to the C drive.

```
C:\work\projects\repo1\...
e:\work\home\me\...
```

When I start git bash I get the following message:

```
sh: rbenv: command not found
sh: cd: /e/home/me: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what the rbenv message relates to, and it is clearly looking for the old home directory. When I use git bash to commit, it asks for my account identity and when I try to reset them I get an error because it is looking for the old home directory:

```
$ git config --global user.email "me"
error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/e/home/me/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

I have tried reinstalling git with no effect. I'm fairly new to git and have tried Google - what am I missing? In case anyone is interested, I host my own git server, although my problem relates to the client use.

Comment: Please could you expand. I removed git using add or remove programs, then re-installed using the installer. At no point did it give me the option to pick a home directory. Did I miss a step? e.g. should I delete all my local .git directories and pull them again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the git bash env shows that HOME is set to the old directory:

```
HOME=/e/home/me
```

Exporting the variable to the new directory fixes my problem for that session. The permanent fix was to edit `C:\Users\me\.bash_profile` in Window's home directory.

Comment: You can also set HOME as a normal Windows environment variable and it will be picked up if you start Git Bash. That helps if you use Git for Windows from the Command Prompt or with GitExtensions as well.